# Change view when a button is touched

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have two view controllers: firstViewController and secondViewController. On the firstViewController I have a button. How can I change the view when I touch the button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)change {

    secondViewController* viewController = [[secondViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    [viewController release];

}
```

Comment: if you get your answer just confirm it by accepted answer sign